# How to Install/Use libcurl with C++ on Windows/Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, eclipse, libcurl

Can someone please explain how to use libcurl with C++ on Windows with Eclipse CDT/Code::Blocks or a similar IDE?

I'm very new to C++ but I know my way around Java very well.

I'm using MinGW but I keep getting this error:

```
C:\Core\src>g++ -I"C:\curl\include\curl" -L"C:\curl\lib64" -lcurldll core.cpp -o
 core.exe
C:\Users\Bob\AppData\Local\Temp\cc2BV0HI.o:core.cpp:(.text+0xc81): undefined
reference to `_imp__curl_easy_init'
C:\Users\Bob\AppData\Local\Temp\cc2BV0HI.o:core.cpp:(.text+0xca7): undefined
reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'
C:\Users\Bob\AppData\Local\Temp\cc2BV0HI.o:core.cpp:(.text+0xcc4): undefined
reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'
C:\Users\Bob\AppData\Local\Temp\cc2BV0HI.o:core.cpp:(.text+0xcd1): undefined
reference to `_imp__curl_easy_perform'
C:\Users\Bob\AppData\Local\Temp\cc2BV0HI.o:core.cpp:(.text+0xce1): undefined
reference to `_imp__curl_easy_cleanup
```

What I've Tried:

- If I give the wrong library path/name it will tell me that it can not find the library. So clearly it FOUND the libcurldll.a/libcurl.a files but it isn't linking with them properly.
- I've tried putting the actual libcurl.dll file from the bin into every source folder possible in my project.
- I've tried going to C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols then added "curl" and "curldll" to libraries and "C:\curl\lib64" to the library search path.
- I've tried manually adding the -lcurl, -lcurldll, -DCURL_STATICLIB, -L"C:\curl\lib64" options to the MinGW Linker tool.

This has been stumping me for days. Please help.

Comment: Suggestion: Switch to Ubuntu until a Windows solution is found. Using libraries/C/C++ is way easier on Ubuntu.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution?